# How to check in php if directory with symlinks exists and if its not to make it

Tags: php, linux, symlink

I have this :

```
move_uploaded_file($File['tmp_name']['File'], $FilePath);
```

Where

```
$FilePath is '/data/www/MIMICm/Common/Upload/PPKInside/CustomImage/6/52'
```

Where **'PPKInside'** is symlink pointing to **'../../MIMI/Common/Data/'** where **'Data'** is symling pointing to **'/mnt/nfsnew/DIDIData/PPKInside/Data'**
So far I found that **'/mnt/nfsnew/'** is empty and **'/DIDIData/PPKInside/Data'** are missing dirs...
**What is the best way to check if the directories exists and to create them if they not ?** Because at the moment

```
is_dir('/data/www/MIMICm/Common/Upload/PPKInside');
```

returns false and I need to use **is_link()** but after the first link ('PPKInside') I can't check if its sub directories exists and create them if needed...

Answer (score 1):

[realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) will expand any symlinks in the given path and tell you whether the final absolute file (directory) exists:

> realpath() returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist.

If it does not exist, you can create the complete directory path in one go, adding missing subdirectories along the way, by using [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) with the `$recursive` flag set.

```
$FilePath = '/data/www/MIMICm/Common/Upload/PPKInside/CustomImage/6/52';

if (!realpath($FilePath)) {
    mkdir($FilePath, 0777, true);
}
```

Note that this particular example creates any directories with read/write/execute permissions for *everybody*. You may want to change the 0777 to better fit your specific setup.

Comment: BUT var_dump(realpath('/data/www/MIMICm/Common/Upload/PPKInside')); returns false AND 'ls -la /data/www/MIMICm/Common/Upload/PPKInside' in shell returns the linked path.... so for some reason realpath() is not working...

Comment: Do you (your web server user) have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy?

Comment: I don't know - how to check ?

Comment: Either manually or using a script [like this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82347/how-to-check-if-a-user-can-access-a-given-file)

Comment: Ok, I'll check and I will write again